# Check if string contains ANY string from the list in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

how to check if a string "I want to eat apples", contains a string from the list of strings?

Here's the code that I'm trying to use:

```
Dim CONTAINER As String() = {"eat", "dog", "cat"}

    If STRING1.Text.Contains(CONTAINER(0..All?)) Then
        Dim ioFileT As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\strings\RANDOMWORD.txt")
        Dim linesT As New List(Of String)
        Dim rndT As New Random()
        Dim lineT As Integer
        Dim RANDOMWORDFROMTXTFILE As String
        While ioFileT.Peek <> -1
            linesT.Add(ioFileT.ReadLine())
        End While
        lineT = rndT.Next(linesT.Count + 0)
        RANDOMWORDFROMTXTFILE = (lines(line).Trim())
        Console.Write(RANDOMWORDFROMTXTFILE)
    End If
```

Comment: Incidentally, you forgot to call `ioFileT.Dispose()` after using it. Or you might be interested in the [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1) method, as in `Dim linesT As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\strings\RANDOMWORD.txt")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
If substringList.Any(Function(s) myString.Contains(s)) Then
    'myString contains at least one item from substringList.
End If
```